# ASP.Net textbox right to left

Tags: asp.net, textbox, right-to-left

In ASP.Net, the cursor is on the left side and I would like to put it on the right side.

In Window form, there is right to left in the properties.

But there is none in ASP.Net

How to achieve so?

Comment: Try the css direction properties: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_direction.asp)

Comment: @ysrb submit that as an answer not a comment

Comment: @qntmfred , sorry. I will next time :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use css style:

```
 { direction:rtl;}
```

edit. example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="ltor"></asp:TextBox>
```

and css:

```
.ltor {direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: +1 Wow, I never knew that a `direction` css property existed. Pretty cool.

Comment: superb, never knew this property

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use the `<dir>` attribute for the specific element as well. [8.2 Specifying the direction of text and tables: the *dir* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2)