# show reverse data in textbox and gridview in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I save users username and password in database But in sign in page when you type something it send reverse data to data base !!
for example I set password : `1023!QAZ` and it save currently in database 
But when you want to log in should Enter reverse !! QAZ!1023
and when show password in grid view show :  `QAZ!1023`

I think its from my password text box ! But I dont know how I can fix it ! 
my password txt aspx code :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my server side code :

```
 protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
        cm.Command.CommandText = "Mysp_tblManage_add";
        cm.Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cm.Command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUser.Text;
        cm.Command.Parameters.Add("@PassWord", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtPass.Text;
        cm.Connection.Open();
        cm.Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cm.Connection.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and my Stored procedure is :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Mysp_tblManage_add]
@UserName nvarchar(15) ,
@PassWord nchar(10) ,

as

BEGIN
insert into tblManage (UserName,PassWord)
values(@UserName,@PassWord)
END
```

picture from gridview :

[image]

picture from data base :

[image]

Comment: That's called "reverse."

Comment: You should include your code that saves the password, not to mention that you shouldn't store the password like that.

Comment: share server side code mechanism of saving?

Comment: do you set page direction ? or password's textbox direction ?

Comment: @NiMa now i text it But , Does not matter

Comment: @mohammad are you sure the textbox direction is still as you set on run time?

Comment: @NiMa i set direction like this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527030/asp-net-textbox-right-to-left

Comment: @mohammad fine,but try { direction:rtl !important;} too,hope it helps